# Collisions remove a jump function in P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I made a platformer and tried to add collision but my code isn't working for some reason, I cant jump anymore I tried redoing the code: here it is
PS I'm new to P5

```
//game control ***(not used rn)***
let level = 0;
//gravity
let minHeight = 375
let direction = 1;
let vel = 2;
let jumpPower = 10;
let fallingSpeed = 1;

//player setup and whatnot
let playerX = 400;
let playerY = 370

let playerWidth = 30;
let playerHeight = 70;

//platform
let platX = 200;
let platY = 300;
let platWidth = 200;
let platHeight = 40;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 500);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  textAlign(CENTER);
}
function gravityControl(){
if (keyIsDown(32)){
  jump = true
}else{
  jump = false
}
}
function draw() {
  background(220);
  movement();
  gravityControl()
  gravity()

  if (level == 0) {
    game();
  }
}

function game() {
  background(150, 230, 240);

  //floor
  noStroke();
  fill("green");
  rect(width / 2, 450, width, 100);

  //platform
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  fill("rgb(218,218,138)");
  rect(platX, platY, platWidth, platHeight);

  //player
  noStroke();
  fill("red");
  rect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
  
  
  
  //collisions
  if (playerX >= platX -platWidth/2 && playerX <= playerX+platWidth/2 && playerY >= platY-platHeight/2 &&playerY<=platY+platHeight/2)
    playerY = playerY
    vel = 0
}

function movement() {
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    playerX -= 3;
  }
  if(keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW) )
    playerX += 3
}
function mousePressed() {
  fullscreen(true);
}

function gravity(){
  if (playerY >= minHeight && jump == false){
    if(playerY >= minHeight){
      playerY = minHeight
    }else{
      vel = fallingSpeed
    }
    playerY = playerY +0
    
  }
  else{
    playerY = playerY + (direction * vel)
  }
  if (jump == true){
    vel = -jumpPower
  }else{
    vel = fallingSpeed
  }
  
}
function gravityControl(){
if (keyIsDown(32)){
  jump = true
}
  else{
  jump = false
  }
}
```

I tried to get rid of the code that make collisions happen and it worked. I would appreciate any help. I am following a tutorial on Youtube and we have identical code. I am expecting it to jump after implementing the collisions but that is not the case
YT link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StoBCNiQakM&list=PLBDInqUM5B26FjwMMZqGDxqQr1kX5V9Ul&index=3

Comment: There appear to be several syntax errors in the code block, such as missing semicolons and mismatched parentheses/curly braces. Since you said it's working other than the jumping part, I'm assuming these are just typos made when transcribing the code for your question. For this reason,  it is usually better to copy & paste the code directly from your editor into the code block here, instead of retyping it all (and it's also a lot faster and easier!) I've fixed these syntax errors in the version that's in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version of your code with some slight changes that fix the jump functionality. I assume you want to be able to land/walk on top of the platform, so my version allows you to do this. Refer to the comments in the code for details on what specifically has been changed.

In particular, note that in your collision condition, it is necessary to test for the two possibilities (colliding with the platform from **above** and from **below**) *separately*.

Also relevant: the P5.js `constrain` function, documentation for which can be found here: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/constrain

---

I tested the new code in the P5.js editor here: https://editor.p5js.org and it seems to do what you intend.

NEW (WORKING) CODE:

```
//game control ***(not used rn)***
let level = 0;
//gravity
let minHeight = 375;
let direction = 1;
let vel = 2;
let jumpPower = 10;
let fallingSpeed = 1;
let onPlatform = false; // NEW: check for whether the player is standing on a platform

//player setup and whatnot
let playerX = 400;
let playerY = 370;

let playerWidth = 30;
let playerHeight = 70;

//platform
let platX = 200;
let platY = 300;
let platWidth = 200;
let platHeight = 40;

        
function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 500);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    textAlign(CENTER);
}
        
function gravityControl() {
    if (keyIsDown(32)) { // keycode 32 = spacebar
        jump = true;
    } else {
        jump = false;
    }
}
function draw() {
    background(220);
    movement();
    gravityControl();
    gravity();

    if (level == 0) {
        game();
    }
}

function game() {
    background(150, 230, 240);

    //floor
    noStroke();
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    rect(width / 2, 450, width, 100);

    //platform
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(4);
    fill(218,218,138);
    rect(platX, platY, platWidth, platHeight);

    //player
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
  
    onPlatform = false; // This new boolean defaults to false unless the correct condition (see below) evaluates to true
          
    //collisions (Added parentheses around each separate condition, and around mathematical expressions within each condition, for more readability)
    // (Player y coordinate - half of player's height) = player's head: check for collisions with BOTTOM of platform
    // (Player y coordinate + half of player's height) = player's feet: check for collisions with TOP of platform
    if ((playerX >= (platX - platWidth/2)) && (playerX <= (platX + platWidth/2))) {
        /* It looks like you're attempting to keep the player's y coordinate from changing once you hit the platform. However, just assigning the variable to itself won't accomplish this. */
        //playerY = playerY; // This line does nothing: removed it
        
        // Instead, you'll need the constrain() function: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/constrain
      
        // If the player rectangle is BELOW the platform, constrain it not to rise any higher
        if (((playerY - playerHeight/2) >= (platY - platHeight/2))) {
            playerY = constrain(playerY, platY + platHeight/2 + playerHeight/2, height);
        }
      
        // If the player rectangle is ABOVE the platform, constrain it not to drop any lower
        else if (((playerY + playerHeight/2) <= (platY + platHeight/2))) {
            playerY = constrain(playerY, 0, platY - platHeight/2 - playerHeight/2);
            if (playerY + playerHeight/2 >= platY - platHeight/2) {
                onPlatform = true; // Don't drop through the platform; stand on it like a solid surface
            }
        }
    }
}

function movement() {
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
        playerX -= 3;
    }
    if(keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
        playerX += 3;
    }
}

/*
function mousePressed() {
    fullscreen(true);
}
*/

function gravity() {
    if (playerY >= minHeight && jump == false) {
        if (playerY > minHeight) {
            playerY = minHeight;
        } //else { // This condition is unnecessary: inside the outer "if" statement, since you've already checked whether playerY is >= minHeight, it can't possibly be less than minHeight
            //vel = fallingSpeed;
        //}
        //playerY = playerY + 0; This doesn't do anything: adding 0 to a number doesn't change it
    }
    else {
        playerY = playerY + (direction * vel);
    }
    if (jump == true){
        vel = -jumpPower;
    } else if (!onPlatform) {
        vel = fallingSpeed;
    } else {
        vel = 0;
    }
}
        
function gravityControl() {
    if (keyIsDown(32)) {
        jump = true;
    }
    else {
        jump = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @helloworld423 Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: this has been a life saver, I appreciate the help!